# MSYS2 cannot be updated in winget

Tags: msys2, winget

winget v1.4.10173

While performing `winget upgrade --all` I got the folowing result:

```
Name               Id             Version   Available Source
------------------------------------------------------------
MariaDB 10.5 (x64) MariaDB.Server 10.5.18.0 10.9.3.0  winget
2 upgrades available.

The following packages have an upgrade available, but require explicit targeting for upgrade:
Name        Id          Version  Available Source
-------------------------------------------------
MSYS2 64bit MSYS2.MSYS2 20220503 20230127  winget
2 package(s) have version numbers that cannot be determined. Use --include-unknown to see all results.
6 package(s) have version numbers that cannot be determined. Use --include-unknown to see all results.
1 package(s) is pinned and needs to be explicitly upgraded.
```

[Some blogs](https://pureinfotech.com/windows-package-manager-1-4-winget-zip-installs/) mention the `--include-explicit` switch but there is no such option in v1.4.10173.

For updating msys2, what I actually want is to run `pacman -Syuu` in msys2 shell. As I understand it, updating msys2 via winget would result in the deletion of all data stored in the current msys2 installation folders. Even if the option `--include-explicit` were available, using it could be fatal.

What is the right way to update **msys2** installed via **winget** then?

Comment: Try updating to 1.5.101

Comment: I tried using the new switch `--include-pinned`, but the result was the same as before. Additionally, I'm unsure about the difference between MariaDB and MSYS2 packages, as both are prevented from upgrading - which is actually a good thing. However, there appear to be two different mechanisms for ensuring their non-upgradability.